# SQL Optimize Best EXPLAIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

```
SELECT op.order_id
FROM order o
JOIN order_product op
USING(order_id)
WHERE o.quantity_complete = 0
GROUP BY op.order_id 
HAVING SUM(op.presale) = 0
```

Is it a good idea to have an index on `op.presale` if the `op.presale` includes only 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't think it'll make any improvement in this case. But you can check yourself! Use EXPLAIN before and after creating the index, and see if there's any difference. I don't think there will be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an index on the column in the `HAVING` clause will have any effect.  However, you can rewrite your query to move the logic in the `HAVING` clause to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    op.order_id
FROM order o
INNER JOIN order_product op
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT order_id
    FROM order_product
    WHERE presale <> 0
) t
    ON op.order_id = t.order_id
WHERE
    o.quantity_complete = 0 AND
    t.order_id IS NULL          -- replaces the HAVING clause
GROUP BY op.order_id
```

The basic idea here to join to a new subquery which finds all `order_id` having at least one presale value which is *not* zero.  Such matching `order_id` would therefore have a sum of presales not equal to zero.  I use a `LEFT JOIN` to this subquery and then retain only order records which do *not* match to this subquery.